# I can't make this JSON

Tags: php, json

I'm currently making a mcq for a medical application and i want to make a Json from my database by a php but it's isn't working, someone advice me to Having a JSONObject for the question and a JSONArray for the Choices but i'm not able to make this and i don't understand why ! I followed a lot a tutorial but i can't figure out why i  can't make this JSON :

```
{ //This is the JSON i want to make !
    "QCM": {
        "question": "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
        "id": "31",
        "choix": ["Oui", "Non"]
    }
}
```

But i can't, currently my PHP code is :

```
$db = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);


$questions = $db->query("SELECT question, id FROM question ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $QCM[] = $row;

$choix = $db->query("SELECT choix FROM choix WHERE id_question = $id ORDER BY rand()");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($choix)) {
    $QCM[] = $row;

    }
}
echo json_encode(array("QCM"=>$QCM));
```

and there is the JSON i can get with this code :

```
{ //I don't want this JSON because i can't read the "choix" in my application
    "QCM": [{
        "question": "Est-ce que Batman gagne contre Superman",
        "id": "30"
    }, {
        "choix": "Oui"
    }, {
        "choix": "Non"
    }]
}
```

I hope someone can help me because i can't make the right json !

Here is my JAVA :

```
try
                        {
                            JSONArray QCM = response.getJSONArray("QCM");
                            for (int i=0; i<QCM.length(); i++) {
                                JSONObject getQcmObject = QCM.getJSONObject(i);
                                String questionGet = getQcmObject.getString("question");
                                symptomesQuestions.setText(questionGet);

                                JSONArray CHOIX = response.getJSONArray("choix");
                                for (int x =0; x<CHOIX.length(); x++){
                                    JSONObject getChoixObject = CHOIX.getJSONObject(x);
                                    String choiceGet = getChoixObject.getString("choix")
                                    lesChoixButton.setText(choiceGet);
                                }
                            }
```

PHP structure required to create the example JSON

```
$jsonPhp = 
    (object) (array(
       'QCM' => 
           (object) (array(
                 'question' => 'Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan',
                 'id' => '31',
                 'choix' => 
            array (
                  0 => 'Oui',
                  1 => 'Non',
            ),
      )),
    ));
```

[Online tool to compare JSON structures for differences...](http://tlrobinson.net/projects/javascript-fun/jsondiff/#%7B%22d%22%3A%7B%22a%22%3A%22%7B%20%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5C%22QCM%5C%22%3A%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22question%5C%22%3A%20%5C%22Est-ce%20que%20Captain%20America%20gagne%20contre%20IronMan%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%20%5C%2231%5C%22%2C%5Cn%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%5C%22choix%5C%22%3A%20%5B%5C%22Oui%5C%22%2C%20%5C%22Non%5C%22%5D%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%2C%22b%22%3A%22%7B%5C%22QCM%5C%22%3A%7B%5C%22question%5C%22%3A%5C%22Est-ce%20que%20Captain%20America%20gagne%20contre%20IronMan%5C%22%2C%5C%22id%5C%22%3A%5C%2231%5C%22%2C%5C%22choix%5C%22%3A%5B%5C%22Oui%5C%22%2C%5C%22Non%5C%22%5D%7D%7D%22%7D%7D)

As print_r:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [QCM] => stdClass Object
        (
            [question] => Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan
            [id] => 31
            [choix] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Oui
                    [1] => Non
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: `$QCM['choix'][] = $row['choix']` in your second fetch loop, then...

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help me, i try that but i get this JSON
`{"QCM":{"0":{"question":"Est-ce que Batman gagne contre Superman","id":"30"},"choix":["Non","Oui"]}}`

Comment: `$QCM = [
                "question" => $row['question']
                "id"       => $row['id'],
                "choix"    => [$row['i dont know what is this']]
            ]`

Comment: every time you use `[]`, you append a **NEW** entry into the array. if you want to build up a child array in pieces, you can't do `$qcm[] = 'this'; $qcm = 'that'`, you end up with two entries. you have to do something like `$temp = array(); $temp[] = 'foo'; $temp[] = 'bar'; $qcm[] = $temp;`

Comment: I don't understand what u are trying to explain @Hendra Nucleo.

Comment: @MarcB Alright, so i must make an array for my question and my choice and put it on my $qcm ?

Comment: Just extend @MarcB comment above, it seems you had correlated between 2 tables. Probably you can use `JOIN` statement rather than running 2 query.

Comment: Yeah but i will get the same question for each choice no ? Because it will show me for exemple :

Are you awesome ? | Yes
Are you awesome ? | No
Are you awesome ? | Probably

in my sql answer right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
<?php

$db         = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$counter    = 0;
$questions  = $db->query("SELECT question, id FROM question ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1");
while($row  = mysqli_fetch_assoc($questions)){
    $id     = $row['id'];
    $QCM[]  = $row;

    $choix  = $db->query("SELECT choix FROM choix WHERE id_question = $id ORDER BY rand()");

    $arrTemp= array();      // HERE A TEMPORAL ARRAY 
    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($choix)) {
        $arrTemp[] = $row2['choix'];
    }
    //TRY THIS:
    $QCM[$counter]["choix"]  = $arrTemp; //ADD THE TEMPORAL ARRAY TO THE $QCM ARRAY
    $counter++;
}
echo json_encode(array("QCM"=>$QCM));
```

I suggest you try this in your Java Code:

```
package com.company;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonExample      = "[{\"QCM\":{\"question\":\"Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan\",\"id\":\"31\",\"choix\":[\"Oui\",\"Non\"]}}, {\"QCM\":{\"question\":\"Do you know who the 1st President of the United States is?\",\"id\":\"32\",\"choix\":[\"Yes\",\"No\"]}}]";
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    try{
        jsonArray           = new JSONArray(jsonExample);

        for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
            JSONObject tempObject   = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            JSONObject qcmObject    = tempObject.getJSONObject("QCM");
            String qcmQuestion      = qcmObject.getString("question");
            JSONArray qcmChoice     = qcmObject.getJSONArray("choix");
            //SET THE TEXT IN THE TEXT FIELD:
            ////symptomesQuestions.setText(qcmQuestion);

            //NOW LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF CHOICES AND DO AS YOU WISH WITH THE CONTENT...
            for(int c=0; c<qcmChoice.length(); c++){
                //BECAUSE YOU MAY HAVE MORE THAN 1 CHOICES, YOU MAY HAVE TO CREATE YOUR BUTTONS DYNAMICALLY...
                //IF YOU SET THE BUTTON TEXT OF lesChoixButton TO ANY VALUE, SUBSEQUENT VALUES IN THE LOOP WILL OVERRIDE IT.
                //SO DYNAMICALLY CREATE YOUR BUTTONS....
                System.out.println( qcmChoice.get(c) + "\n");   // PRINTS Oui   Non...  AND THEN Yes    No  
                ////lesChoixButton.setText(qcmChoice.get(c));
            }

            System.out.print(qcmQuestion);
            System.out.print("\n\n");
            System.out.print(qcmChoice);
            System.out.print("\n\n");

        }
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
}
}
```

Test this Code:

```
package com.company;

    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.*;


    public class Main extends JFrame{

        Main(String g){
            super(g);     
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String jsonExample      = "[{\"QCM\":{\"question\":\"Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan\",\"id\":\"31\",\"choix\":[\"Oui\",\"Non\"]}}, {\"QCM\":{\"question\":\"Do you know who the 1st President of the United States is?\",\"id\":\"32\",\"choix\":[\"Yes\",\"No\"]}}]";
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            try{
                jsonArray           = new JSONArray(jsonExample);
                Main fr             = new Main("QCM QUESTIONS");
                fr.setLayout(new GridLayout(10,10));
                final JPanel  tempPanel     = new JPanel();
                tempPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,4));

                for(int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject tempObject   = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    JSONObject qcmObject    = tempObject.getJSONObject("QCM");
                    String qcmQuestion      = qcmObject.getString("question");
                    JSONArray qcmChoice     = qcmObject.getJSONArray("choix");
                    JTextField  tempQuest   = new JTextField(20);
                    tempQuest.setText(qcmQuestion);
                    fr.add(tempQuest);

                    //SET THE TEXT IN THE TEXT FIELD:
                    ////symptomesQuestions.setText(qcmQuestion);

                    //NOW LOOP THROUGH THE ARRAY OF CHOICES AND DO AS YOU WISH WITH THE CONTENT...
                    for(int c=0; c<qcmChoice.length(); c++){
                        //BECAUSE YOU MAY HAVE MORE THAN 1 CHOICES, YOU MAY HAVE TO CREATE YOUR BUTTONS DYNAMICALLY...
                        //IF YOU SET THE BUTTON TEXT OF lesChoixButton TO ANY VALUE, SUBSEQUENT VALUES IN THE LOOP WILL OVERRIDE IT.
                        //SO DYNAMICALLY CREATE YOUR BUTTONS....
                        System.out.println( qcmChoice.get(c) + "\n");   // PRINTS Oui   Non...  AND THEN Yes    No
                        final JButton  tempBtn     = new JButton();
                        tempBtn.setAlignmentX(0);
                        tempBtn.setAlignmentY(20 + 20*c);
                        tempBtn.setSize(new Dimension(150, 30));

                        tempBtn.setText( (String)qcmChoice.get(c) );
                        fr.add(tempBtn);
                       //fr.add(tempBtn);
                        ////lesChoixButton.setText(qcmChoice.get(c));
                    }
                    final JLabel tempSpacer     = new JLabel( " " );
                    tempSpacer.setText( "  ");
                    fr.add(tempSpacer);

                    System.out.print(qcmQuestion);
                    System.out.print("\n\n");
                    System.out.print(qcmChoice);
                    System.out.print("\n\n");

                }

                fr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                fr.setVisible(true);
                fr.setSize(300,300);
            }catch (Exception e){

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for help ! it's doesn't work actully, can't access to my "choix" in my app

Comment: I just updated the answer. Try if this works for your... added $counter variable.

Comment: `$QCM[counter]` should be `$QCM[$counter]`.

Comment: I don't know why but now it's working, i'm sucessfully getting my question but in my code, i make a button for each choice but i'm only getting one button with all choice in it as if all my choice are only one string

Comment: @FriedrichDylan Maybe due to caching.
Anyways, seeing one button instead of multiple is to be expected because "choix" is an Array. In order to have more than 1 Button (1 for "Oui", 1 for "Non" for example) you should loop through the content of the "choix" Array treat each Value as a single entity.

Comment: Hum i tried that but i can't get only my choice one by one, i edited my question and put my JAVA code, if you can explain how to do it, that will be great :)

Answer (score 0):

Just make self populated data(in your case it populated from database).

```
$expected = [
    "QCM" => [
            "question" => "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
            "id"       => "31",
            "choix"    => ["Oui", "Non"]
        ]
    ];

echo (json_encode($expected , JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
```

Result:

[image]

Guessing from your code, probably:

```
$QCM = [ 
    "question" => $row['question'],
     "id" => $row['id'], 
     "choix" => [$row['i dont know column name']
]
```

Hint:

"QCM" will be your main array key, meanwhile question, id, choix is an array key inside "QCM". You can make json structure like image above using:

```
$expected = [
    "QCM" => [
            "question" => "Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan",
            "id"       => "31",
            "choix"    => ["Oui", "Non"]
        ]
    ];
```

equal to:

```
$q['QCM']['question'] = 'Est-ce que Captain America gagne contre IronMan ';
$q['QCM']['id'] = 31;
$q['QCM']['choix'] = ['Oui', 'Non'];
```

Like what @MarkB said on comment.

Comment: Okay, i trying this now, it give me the right syntax for my json but qcm is null, i'm trying to understand why ! i will be back :) thx

Comment: Try the code below... it's a bit modified. perhaps it helps.